# How to use sshpass to supply a password on the second ssh hop

Tags: ssh

NB: this may seem to be identical with [this SO question](https://superuser.com/q/606252/138891). It is related but not identical (plus its in a different StackExchange site). In that question the author asks for a way to execute a command in a distant system. In this question I am asking how to open (and maintain) a shell over two SSH connections.

I have to go through an intermediate machine (let's call it `$gateway`) to reach my `$server`. So my typical workflow is:

```
ssh $gateway (supply password manually)
ssh $server (supply password manually)
```

I am able to configure SSH public key authentication on the hop to the `$gateway` but not on the second hop to the `$server`. So the best I can do is:

```
ssh $gateway (no password necessary)
ssh $server (supply password manually)
```

My question is: can I use `sshpass` or some other method to supply the password on the second hop? I don't have privileges to install `sshpass` or any other software on the `$gateway` machine.

Comment: The answer is the same as the question you linked. Just don't pass a remote command.

Comment: @Patrick. I agree. I tried to flag it as duplicate but apparently the system doesn't consider it a duplicate since the linked question was asked in a different StackExchange community (superuser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ProxyCommand`:

```
sshpass -p server_password ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p $gateway" $server
```

It will run the `sshpass` from your local host.

Comment: What should be used in the place of `%h` and `%p`?

Comment: this gives me: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname <server-name>: Name or service not known` (where <server-name> is the value I used for `$server`)

Comment: %h and %p should stay there as it is. Sorry, I swapped the server and gateway. Now it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You can try expect to ignore manual password entry -

```
vipin@kali:~$ cat kk.sh
#!/usr/bin/expect 
    set password 1               #set password to 1 (hardcoded)
    spawn ssh kali@kali          # user and hostname is kali
    expect "password"
    send "$password\r"
    interact                     # to get the shell prompt
vipin@kali:~$ ./kk.sh            # execute it and you are in new server
```